# Use attributes to avoid invalid input arguments

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a Method which Takes Int as Input

public void GetMonth(int Month)
  {
  }

Now when I call this method I want to make sure that Compiler generates and Error Message when someone enters number which does not fall between 1-12.

e.g

obj.GetMonth(14)--Here it should give error and does not compile

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

That will be a feature in 4.0, thanks to [code-contracts](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/11/11/introduction-to-code-contracts-melitta-andersen.aspx), which allow you to declare exactly that. But not yet. You'll need to have validation code at runtime:

```
if(month < 1 || month > 12) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("month");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using [**Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.task.aspx) but it sounds like hard tasks.
This class can help to **generate build time errors**.
But the really **hard part, is to make code analysis** to decide when you need to stop the build.